# Programatically create a datagridview with a certain column and row

Tags: c#

I would want to create a DataGridView in C# of 100 cols and 300 rows(let say)..

And so far I realized it was really slow to create the datagridview (by the time the whole grid is done, its a minute already) because i am adding the rows one by one using a for loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Global_Map.Rows; i++)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Is there a faster way to define the number of rows in the datagridview?

Comment: You can set rowcount and columncount. You can also create the rows in a list or array and then use .Rows.AddRange

Answer (score 0):

You could do a data source and databind. Generally performance tuning data gridview can be done by few steps.

1. AutoSizeColumnMode to none.
2. Setting RowHeaderVisible to false and setting it back to true after databinding
3. Setting RowHeadersWidthSizeMode to EnableResizing

You can also try using alternatives like iGrid. It's been many years that I have used DataGridvView so not really sure about any latest alternatives.

Hope this helps.